# Summarize Google Places Data

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-places-api

I need to make a job that summarize amount of business in one specific region (district, city, province or country).
I would like to use the Google Places API, but this returns only until 60 places. In one city, for example, it can there are more que 30,000 places register in Google Maps.
I need this places for summarize per type (restaurant, coffee, hotel, school, etc...)

I also know that there is the term of use which says that no one is allowed to store any information of Google places in personal Database.

How can I start this job, a little clue where to start already help me.

Comment: When I said summarize, I want to say that I want to count the amount places per type or category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you can refer to [Google Maps Places API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) to learn more about the Places API. You can also implement it in the client side by using the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) of Maps JavaScript API.

To achieve what you want, you can use the [Places Nearby Search](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/places/web-service/search#nearby-search-and-text-search-responses). You will use a ***location*** parameter to specify latitude/longitude around which to retrieve place information with a ***radius*** parameter set to a smaller value. Then use the ***type*** parameter to specify the type of place you want to get the count. Setting this lower value of radius and type of place is suggested to be inside the [60 results limit](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging). Also, don't forget to always use your ***API key*** in your requests to the Places API.

You can do something like this [simple code](https://jsfiddle.net/xpce3drq/) I created in client side.

This is where I set the parameter requests:

```
var request = {
    location: sydney,
    radius: '100',
    type: ['restaurant']
  };
```

This is where the nearbySearch request is being called:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
      }

      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

      document.getElementById("numPlaces").innerHTML = results.length;
      document.getElementById("typePlaces").innerHTML = request.type;
    }
  });
}
```

The API key was set in the script that is calling the API:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Pagemag, thanks for answering! I did this, but in one city may have more that 60 restaurants. I searched in documentation some that did the function "count".